# Sorting Core Data results into NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an entity `Tag` with string property `tagName`. I went to fetch all objects in this Entity into a `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I want Tag with `tagName` "Main" to be the first object. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor2 =
[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"tagName" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* tag1, NSString* tag2) {
    NSLog(@"compare");
    if ([tag1 isEqualToString:@"main"]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if ([tag2 isEqualToString:@"main"]) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [tag1 compare:tag2];
}] autorelease];  

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lastDescriptor2]];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;   

if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

This code is called in my `viewDidLoad` method, and is only called once. The first time it's called, for some reason the sortDescriptor here doesn't apply - it just doesn't get called (the `NSLog` statement doesn't show up either). My results are returning solely based on the `BOOL` value I specify for `ascending` - the block is ignored.

But when I insert a new `Tag` object into the `MOC` and the `NSFetchedResultsController` update delegate methods are called, the actual sortDescriptor gets applied, and the `NSLog(@"compare")` finally appears, but only when I make updates to the objects! No matter what I've tried, I can't get the sort to apply to the initial fetch.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Mohabitar, Have you tried using a standard sort descriptor instead of one with a custom comparator? I say this because there are some odd unspecified rules about what kinds of operations can actually be applied with a fetch to the store. Also, I suggest you isolate your testing to just the NSFetchRequest. The results controller is added noise. IOW, make sure the fetch works. Then worry about displaying it. Andrew

Comment: Ya everything works properly with a normal sort descriptor. The fetch is executing. My results are even fetched alphabetically with this sort descriptor above, so everything is working. And I tried this exact sort descriptor on a normal fetch request without NSFetchedResultsController, and it worked just fine. Its just the NSFetchedResultsController thats giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably seen at one point or another, if the predicate you pass into your NSFetchRequest is a block predicate, your fetch request will fail. This happens because CoreData needs to translate your predicate into SQL so it can run it against the database. The result is that a predicate is never actually compared against the objects that result from the fetch request.

The same is true of sort descriptors. The fetch request does not perform the comparison against the objects when the fetch is performed. It is passed as part of the SQL.

You also describe an interesting exception to the rules I describe above. When you have an existing NSFetchedResultsController and add an object to the NSManagedObjectContext, the NSFetchedResultsController is updated by evaluating the NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor against the object, rather than converting them to SQL.